# Derivative Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, derivative

I have a 42x39 matrix in R.

[image: Extract from my data set being used]

I'm trying to achieve the first derivative of the Y variables for each X and haven't found anything online that works.

Comment: *"achieve the first derivative of the Y variables for each X"* I don't understand your question. The "Y variables for each X" give scalars. Where is your expression?

Comment: I should've been clearer, I'd like each cell to be the difference between it and the cell above it, if that makes any sense

Comment: Can you please include minimal sample data in your post; screenshots are never useful as we can't copy&paste data/code. It would help with understanding your problem if you were to also provide your expected output for the sample data you give.

Comment: I have sent an edit to change the title to difference matrix, change back if I have misunderstood your question. A derivative matrix, at least where I am from, is a matrix of partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the difference between a cell and the cell above it you can use the `diff` function. First read your data in as a `dataframe`.

just to see how it works try `diff(c(1, 3))`

Below is a quick way to do it and return a new data frame.

```
lapply(YourDataFrame, diff) %>% 
  dplyr::bind_cols()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide sample let's generate a `6x6` sample matrix

```
set.seed(2018)
mat <- matrix(sample(36), nrow = 6)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]   13   19   24   21   31   33
#[2,]   17    4   32   28   20    8
#[3,]    3   27   18    5   29   30
#[4,]    7   15   14    9   25   36
#[5,]   16   11    6   34   23   22
#[6,]   10   35   26    2    1   12
```

We can now calculate the difference of every cell with the cell above it using `apply` with `MARGIN = 2`

```
apply(mat, 2, function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]    4  -15    8    7  -11  -25
#[3,]  -14   23  -14  -23    9   22
#[4,]    4  -12   -4    4   -4    6
#[5,]    9   -4   -8   25   -2  -14
#[6,]   -6   24   20  -32  -22  -10
```